# LinkedList: What to substitute for node on the last node?

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list, null, nodes

This is what my constructor looks like in my `LinkedNode` class:

```
int info;
LinkedNode next;

public LinkedNode(int info, LinkedNode next) { 
    this.info = info;
    this.next = next;
}
```

In my `Test` (main) class, when I try to create the nodes as such:

```
LinkedNode d = new LinkedNode(40, null);
LinkedNode c = new LinkedNode(30, d);
LinkedNode b = new LinkedNode(20, c);
LinkedNode a = new LinkedNode(10, new LinkedNode(20, LinkedNode(30, LinkedNode(40, null))));
```

, then I get a compiler error telling me

> The method LinkedNode(int, null) is undefined for the type of Test

And it's true since the 2nd parameter of my constructor is of LinkedNode type, but then how do I signify that the last node's `next` is empty?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the 'new' keyword

Comment: where exactly??

Comment: d, c and b LinkedNode are not linked with a. You should not do rather  :
`LinkedNode a = new LinkedNode(10, b)`

Comment: Argh! Thanks, i got it, i missed it twice, so it had nothing to do with the 'null' keyword, i assume, right?

Comment: Each time you want to create a new linked node you need to call the constructor with the new keyword. In your last line of code it looks like you intended to pass in new instances of linked node, but you're actually calling a method that doesn't exist. Hence the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code would be syntactically correct (the `new` keyword was missing as chatton already said)

```
LinkedNode a = new LinkedNode(10, 
    new LinkedNode(20, 
        new LinkedNode(30, 
            new LinkedNode(40, null))));
```

But maybe you mean

```
LinkedNode a2 = new LinkedNode(10, b);
```

instead?

Comment: Yes I did use what you have in your second code, but just wanted to try a different, recursive-ish way to go about it. My only question now is I assume 'null' is of type LinkedNode (or whatever node) and can be had as the second parameter in my case, correct?

Comment: Yes, having null as the second parameter is completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedNode d = new LinkedNode(40, null);
LinkedNode c = new LinkedNode(30, d);
LinkedNode b = new LinkedNode(20, c);
LinkedNode a = new LinkedNode(10, new LinkedNode(20, new LinkedNode(30, new LinkedNode(40, null))));
```

[You can also use this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UJ2XtgRtMk)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your code but it works when add new keyword.

```
LinkedNode c = new LinkedNode(10, new LinkedNode(20, new LinkedNode(30, new LinkedNode(40, null))));
```